# Formatting equations?

Tags: java, formatting, format, equation

I'm new to Java, and I'm trying to format an equation with int elements in an array (I keep getting the error "not a statement"). This is the bit of code:

```
    int n = 0;
    int[] time = {mins, mins2, mins3, mins4, mins5};
    for(int j = 0; j <= 3; j++){
        if (time[j] < time[j+1]){
            n = time[j];
        }
    }
    for(int k = 0; k <= 4; k++){
        time[k] - n;
    }
```

I found the smallest int (all elements are from a random number generator), and now I want to subtract the smallest from every element and permanently change the elements of the given array to those smaller numbers. I don't know how to format the "time[k] - n;" segment correctly.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Well, you subtract `time[k] - n`, but what should be done with the result?

Answer (score 2):

The line:

```
time[k] - n
```

Does *nothing*. It takes the value `time[k]` and subtracts the value `n` from it. It then discards the result.

What you want is to subtract `n` from the variable and assign the result back to the *same variable*:

```
time[k] = time[k] - n
```

In Java, this is equivalent to a [compound assignment operator](http://java.about.com/od/c/g/compoundassgnment.htm):

```
time[k] -= n
```

If you have Java 8 you could in fact do:

```
int[] time = {mins, mins2, mins3, mins4, mins5};
int min = IntStream.of(time).min().getAsInt();
int[] normalised = IntStream.of(time).map(i -> i - min).toArray();
```

And even with earlier versions of Java I would recommend:

```
int[] time = {mins, mins2, mins3, mins4, mins5};
int n = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
for (int t : time) {
    n = Math.min(n, t);
}
for (int i = 0; i < time.length; ++i) {
    time[i] -= n;
}
```

i.e. use a [foreach loop](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/foreach.html) where you can and otherwise use the `length` property of the array rather than hardcoding the length.

Comment: That solved it! Thanks. I didn't even think about adding "time[k] =" beforehand (felt kinda stupid for this one). The quick response is very much appreciated. Compiles, and works perfectly. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Change `time[k] - n;` to `time[k] =- n;`. So it will store `time[k] - n` in `time[k]`